# Java: connect Scala module

Tags: java, scala

I want to use in my program Java OOP benefits for code structurization and Scala functional approach benefits for implementing algorithms with recursion.

*How can I compose Java and Scala functionality in my application?*

*Actually I mean how I can connect a fewq Scala classes to my java web app?*

Comment: No, I've already learn Java and the basics of Scala. So I won't switch to C#. Besides of all, Scala is also OOP, but as I've mentioned, my knowledges are very shallow

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/ are you looking for such thing?

Comment: The interoperabilty between Java and Scala classes is well defined: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/faq/4, so "the proof is in the pudding". It is easy to implement Java interfaces with a Scala class; or use a Scala class in place of a Java class.

Comment: No, it seems not a thing I search for. I have some algorithm that require recursion. I can use deep recursion in Java because I will get StackOverflowException. But Scala has such a beautiful thing as tail recursion. So I decide to implement my algorithms in Scala

Comment: @Gyro Gearless please, provide a reference to an example

Comment: @NickoleAbs I suggest you provide the recursive algorithm. Almost certainly it can be written in Java without a StackOverflowException.

Comment: My algorithm - finding longest common subsequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example i was lately working on:

In Alfresco, a webscript (kinda servlet on steroids, in fact this now part of the Spring framework) is defined using the following Java interfaces / classes:

```
public interface WebScript
{
  /**
 * Execute the Service
 * 
 * @param req   WebScriptRequest representing the request to this service
 * @param res   WebScriptResponse encapsulating the result of this service
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void execute(WebScriptRequest req, WebScriptResponse res)
    throws IOException;
}
```

Now I can easily define a base class for Scala webscripts, introducing logging and some boilerplate code as Scala traits:

```
abstract class WebscriptBase extends AbstractWebScript with ServiceBase with Logging {
   // "ServiceBase" and "Logging" are two Scala traits 
}
```

And the I define an webscript class, overriding the abstract method declared in the original Java interface:

```
class SampleWebscript extends WebscriptBase {

  override def execute(req: WebScriptRequest, response: WebScriptResponse): Unit = {

  try {
    response.setContentType(MIMETYPE_JSON)
    val writer = new PrintWriter (response.getWriter)
    writer.println("{'Hopp':'Topp'}")
  }

 }

 }
```

Finally, I use this class (written in Scala) in a Spring bean configuration:

```
<bean id="webscript.de.treufuss.dedup.helloWorld.get" parent="webscript" class="de.treufuss.alfresco.service.dedup.webscript.SampleWebscript">
</bean>
```

Note the "SampleWebscript" class just looks and feels like a plain java class - the only magic is the translation from Java's method signature into Scala syntax!

Answer (score 1):

Writing code in Scala does not prevent StackOverflowError. Unless your recursive method can be written as tail recursion, in which case Scala compiler may actually compile it into a loop.

Simple function like this will cause StackOverflowError

```
def f(i: Long):Long = i match {
    case 1 => 1
    case n => f(n-1) + n
}
```

When I tested in Scala REPL, `6095` is enough to blow it.

A tail-recursive version can be like

```
def f(i: Long):Long = {
    @tailrec
    def ff(ii: Long, ans: Long): Long = ii match {
        case 0 => ans
        case n => ff(ii-1, ans + n)
    }
    ff(i, 0)
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Actually, for that reason I've tried to connect scala-module